# Create java class from xml file using apache axis and xsd schema

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, axis, wsdl2java

I have WSDL and XSD files describing some documents.

I'm using apache axis 1.4 to generate Java proxy classes from WSDL schema. The classes are generated successfully but they don't contain annotations like `@XmlRootElement`, `@XmlAttribute` and others. Generated classes do not contain any annotations at all.

Then I have xml files which I extract from JMS queue. I remove headers and try to deserialize (unmarshall) the xml to correct Java proxy class.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(SalesOrder.class);
StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("D:\\Sources\\NSJavaClientCRM2014-1\\data\\jms&SL_IN---salesorder2014_1.xml");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement<SalesOrder> je1 = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, SalesOrder.class);
SalesOrder salesOrder = je1.getValue();
```

as a result I get a lot of IllegalAnnotationsException like this:

```
com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2014_1.types.RecordType does not have a no-arg default constructor.
com.netsuite.webservices.platform.common_2014_1.types.AvsMatchCode does not have a no-arg default constructor.
```

I cannot add annotations manually, because the generated Java classes are really huge. This is the place where I'm stuck. So from my point of view the problem is in absence of XML annotations in Java proxy classes and I have no idea how to add them automatically when generating classes from wsdl schema.

The question is complicated:

We have WSDL and XSD schema and we have a lot of XML files created according to schema.
How can I create correct Java proxy classes (with XML annotations or without) and easily do the marshalling / unmarshalling to/from ordinary XML files? Maybe there some options in axis?

Comment: I'm not sure how it is done in AXIS, but normally you use XJC (or tools based on that) to generate schema-derived classes. I'll retag to JAXB for the right audience.

Comment: I've tried to use XJC from jdk. It generates classes with annotations, but every XML file fails during deserialization. Seems XJC builds incorrect XML or I am doing something wrong.